# Change post date for testing purposes

Tags: date, testing

Is there a way I can change a post date to preferably a different month and a year for testing purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this from the dashboard, enter the post and on the right hand side you can edit the published date.

Comment: Aha, it was right in front of me all along. Thank you :)

Comment: Please tick the answer :)

Comment: Will do just need to wait 5 more minutes for it to let me :)